# Can a woman sneeze in public if it draws attention?

Tags: tznius-modesty

Based on an assumption that a woman should not draw attention to herself in public, can it be considered lack of Tznius to sneeze in public?

Is one required to attempt to stifle sneezes even if it has a potential health hazard or if one has allergies?

Comment: Buchor amid, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] this question to include some indication of why you think there may be such a requirement. Is this a requirement you've learned of in some class? Is it something you've seen observed in practice?

Comment: Welcome to MY! Please take a moment to check out our [tour] for some useful information about the site.

Comment: 11 downvotes? Really? On a question that was asked so recently, by a new user? (That's not to say that I think it is the best question ever asked, but please, people!)

Answer (score 4):

Talmud in Bechorot 44b says, a man can urinate even in public to avoid health problems. Because, at least at the Talmud time, one could be ill and sterile if he was retaining from urinating.

So, IMHO, a fortiori here, a woman should never retain from sneezing for the [health problems](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2018/01/15/dont-hold-sneeze-warn-doctors-could-death/) that could arise.

Besides the serious lack of sources to the assumption that sneezing in public shall be not tznius.

Comment: AFAIK In Talmudic times, they had everyone urinating in public, It wasn't considered indecent see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet#Ancient_history

Comment: @AlBerko From the sugya in Bechorot seems, it *was* considered embarrassing (and maybe indecent), but for the sake of health...

Comment: I +1 your answer, I liked your logic, though. Keep in mind that the Talmud spans hundreds of years and different kingdoms. Different times different customs. I just point to the fact that in ancient Greece and Rome it wasn't so embarrassing.

Comment: @Al If you haven't seen already, check [Berakhot 23a-b](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_23.html). I wouldn't say based on this that it was considered acceptable to urinate wherever you happened to be...

Comment: @AlBerko for the general population, yes. But Jewish customs might have been different, which they usually are

Answer (score -2):

Only sexually appealing behaviors that draw attention to woman's body are forbidden, such as bright or immodest clothes.

A woman that carries a triplet stroller is not considered Not Tznuah even if it draws a lot of public attention.

Comment: @Buchoramid I don’t think we’re concerned for such a small group of people. Most people do not have a sneezing fetish. Would you say that we’re concerned for people attracted to tichels or wigs?

Comment: @DonieF   You would be surprised as to the number of people   i have encountered this in my family and view it as potential threat